# Why mysql query is updating what is not needed?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am working on a web tool in flask to create xls files automatically, so I tried to make a kind of edition of a row in the mysql database, but the catch is that I only want to update the value if the data in the web form (not in the database) is not NULL here is my query

```
UPDATE Servi 
SET Orden = CASE WHEN Orden IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,
    Dependencia = CASE WHEN Dependencia IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END, 
    Atencion = CASE WHEN Atencion IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,  
    Recibio_del_cer = CASE WHEN Recibio_del_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Entrego_al_cer = CASE WHEN Entrego_al_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,   
    Folio = CASE WHEN Entrego_al_cer IS NOT NULL THEN '%s' END,    
    ...
    ...
    ...  
WHERE Orden=WHERE Orden='%s'
```

Now my problem here is that the query is updating a lot of things as NULL (I guess), here are 2 pictures, one shows the data from an specific `Orden` next to the textbox to enter the new data, in the other picture we can see what happens to the row when is updated; here in my example I changed the second value (`Dependencia`) from "policia" to "transito" and left empty the others spaces

[image]

[image]

What I get is a lot of data loss, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, even what I'm doing... here is the code of the form

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}
{% block title %}Registro de usuarios{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="Orden">Orden: </label>
        <input type="text" id="Orden" placeholder="{{data}}" name="Orden" required  /><br>
        <label for="Dependencia">Dependencia: </label>
        <input type="text" id="Dependencia" name="Dependencia" /><br>
        <label for="Atencion">Atencion: </label>
        <input type="text" id="Atencion" name="Atencion" /><br>
        <label for="Recibio_del_cer">Recibio del cer: </label>
        <input type="text" id="Recibio_del_cer" name="Recibio_del_cer" /><br>
        <label for="Entrego_al_cer">Entrego al cer: </label>
        <input type="text" id="Entrego_al_cer" name="Entrego_al_cer" /><br>
       ...
       ...
       ...
    
    <input type="submit" id="send-signup" name="signup" value="Registrar" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope you can help me, I want to change the value of the entry only if there are text in the textbox on the form. Thanks in advance

**Edit**: this is the code that I use to apply the query hope it helps

```
def edicion_form(order):
   
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Servi WHERE Orden='%s'"%order
        mycursor.execute(sql)
        result = mycursor.fetchall()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Orden = request.form['Orden']
            Dependencia = request.form['Dependencia']
            Atencion = request.form['Atencion']
            Recibio_del_cer = request.form['Recibio_del_cer']
            Entrego_al_cer = request.form['Entrego_al_cer']
            Folio = request.form['Folio']
            Entrada = request.form['Entrada']
            Equipo = request.form['Equipo']
            Marca = request.form['Marca']
            Modelo = request.form['Modelo']
            Serie = request.form['Serie']
            Unidad = request.form['Unidad']
            Delegacion = request.form['Delegacion']
            Accesorio = request.form['Accesorio']
            Falla = request.form['Falla']
            Ticket = request.form['Ticket']
            Status = request.form['Status']
            Reparacion = request.form['Reparacion']
            Salida = request.form['Salida']
            Reparo = request.form['Reparo']
            Servicio = request.form['Servicio']
            Reporte = request.form['Reporte']
            sql2  = "UPDATE Servi SET Orden= case when Orden is not null then '%s' ELSE Orden end, Dependencia=case when Dependencia is not null then '%s' ELSE Dependencia end, Atencion=case when Atencion is not null then '%s' ELSE Atencion end, Recibio_del_cer=case when Recibio_del_cer is not null then '%s' ELSE Recibio_del_cer end, Entrego_al_cer=case when Entrego_al_cer is not null then '%s' ELSE Entrego_al_cer end, Folio=case when Entrego_al_cer is not null then '%s' ELSE Folio end, Entrada=case when Entrego_al_cer is not null then '%s' ELSE Entrada end, Equipo=case when Equipo is not null then '%s' ELSE Equipo end, Marca=case when Marca is not null then '%s' ELSE Marca end,  Modelo=case when Modelo is not null then '%s' ELSE Modelo end,  Serie=case when Serie is not null then '%s' ELSE Serie end,  Unidad=case when Unidad is not null then '%s' ELSE Unidad end,  Delegacion=case when Delegacion is not null then '%s' ELSE Delegacion end,  Accesorio=case when Accesorio is not null then '%s' ELSE Accesorio end,  Falla=case when Falla is not null then '%s' ELSE Falla end,  Ticket=case when Ticket is not null then '%s' ELSE Ticket end, Status=case when Status is not null then '%s' ELSE Status end,  Reparacion=case when Reparacion is not null then '%s' ELSE Reparacion end, Salida=case when Salida is not null then '%s' ELSE Salida end, Reparo=case when Reparo is not null then '%s' ELSE Reparo end, Servicio=case when Servicio is not null then '%s' ELSE Servicio end, Reporte=case when Reporte is not null then '%s' ELSE Reporte end WHERE Orden='%s'" %(Orden, Dependencia, Atencion, Recibio_del_cer, Entrego_al_cer, Folio, Entrada, Equipo, Marca, Modelo, Serie, Unidad, Delegacion, Accesorio, Falla, Ticket, Status, Reparacion, Salida, Reparo, Servicio, Reporte, Orden)
            mycursor = conn.cursor()
            mycursor.execute(sql2)
            conn.commit()
            return redirect("/edicion")
```

Answer (score 1):

Either dynamically build your query and only include those things you want to change, or add an ELSE to each CASE that keeps the current value, like:

```
Folio = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE Folio END
```

But it's not clear to me why you are testing like `Orden IS NOT NULL`; that is testing if the current value is not null, not the user input.  If you need help with that, you are going to need to show your code that is constructing the query, not the form.

It sounds like you want to be testing if the value from the form is non-empty; you would do that like:

```
Folio = CASE WHEN LENGTH('%s') THEN '%s' ELSE Folio END
```

but you have to supply each value twice, and just omitting the Folio= clause if Folio is not set in the form makes so much more sense.

Comment: well i want to test if is not null but not on database but in the form textbox, i want to change the value on the data only if the form textbox for that value is not null, the main point here is that i want to edit a value in the row but to do that i need to write all the entries in the form so i want to edit the value only if the textbox in the form is not empty. build it dynamically would be a great option if i knew how to do that, i will look how to do it but i think  that the problem is that i have a difference between what i want and what i am asking to do

Comment: input from your form isn't going to be null, it's going to be empty strings.  as I said, you are going to need to show your code that is constructing the query

Comment: i updated the post up here, i hope it helps, should i use an "" for the querry?